# Keycloak js adapter and Angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, keycloak

I'm developing a CMS AngularJS Single Page with using Single Sign with Keycloak. But there is a problem using angular ui-router with Keycloak JS.

Redirection loop is created when the page loads.

So it is rerouting:

```
https://website.com/#/code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But the result should be the following:

```
https://website.com/#code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

and then look like this:

```
https://website.com/#/
```

The code is as follows:

```
var consoleBaseUrl = window.location.href;
consoleBaseUrl = consoleBaseUrl.substring( 0, consoleBaseUrl.indexOf( "/platform" ) );
consoleBaseUrl = consoleBaseUrl + "/platform";
var auth = {};
var realm = "passqlub";

console.log( consoleBaseUrl );

/** PassQlub Angular App Initialice and dependency load. */
var app = angular.module( "PassQlub", [
    'ui.router',
    'ngSanitize'
] );
```

### Run App Block

```
app
    .run( [
        '$rootScope',
        '$state',
        '$stateParams',
        '$http',
        '$window',
        '$timeout',
        function ( $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $http, $window, $timeout ) {

        }
    ] );
```

### Logout Keycloak Function

```
var logout = function () {
    console.log( "*** PassQlub: logout..." );
    auth.loggedIn = false;
    auth.authz = null;
    window.location = auth.logoutUrl;
};

/** Keycloak Element */
angular.element( document ).ready( function () {
    var keycloakAuth = new Keycloak( "keycloak.json" );
    auth.loggedIn = false;

    keycloakAuth.init( { onLoad: 'login-required' } ).success( function () {
        auth.loggedIn = true;
        auth.authz = keycloakAuth;
        auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl + "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent( "https://" + location.hostname + "/platform" );
        app.factory( 'Auth', function () {
            return auth;
        } );
        //angular.bootstrap( document, [ "PassQlub" ] );
    } ).error( function () {
        window.location.reload();
    } );
} );
```

### Interceptors Factory

```
app.factory( 'authInterceptor', function ( $q, Auth ) {
    return {
        request: function ( config ) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if ( Auth.authz.token ) {
                Auth.authz.updateToken( 5 ).success( function () {
                    config.headers = config.headers || {};
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Auth.authz.token;

                    deferred.resolve( config );
                } ).error( function () {
                    deferred.reject( 'Failed to refresh token' );
                } );
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
} );
```

### Interceptors Factory Errors

```
app.factory( 'errorInterceptor', function ( $q ) {
    return function ( promise ) {
        return promise.then( function ( response ) {
            return response;
        }, function ( response ) {
            if ( response.status == 401 ) {
                console.log( '*** PassQlub: Session Timeout' );
                logout();
            } else if ( response.status == 403 ) {
                alert( "PassQlub: Forbidden" );
            } else if ( response.status == 404 ) {
                alert( "PassQlub: Not found" );
            } else if ( response.status ) {
                if ( response.data && response.data.errorMessage ) {
                    alert( response.data.errorMessage );
                } else {
                    alert( "PassQlub: An unexpected server error has occurred" );
                }
            }
            return $q.reject( response );
        } );
    };
} );
```

Comment: The variable `auth` is on the global namespace. Could it be conflicting with another library? Also on document ready, there is an error handler that reloads the document? Console log the error to see what is causing the reload.